# Base controller for exporting data to excel instead of returning viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a `Web API` project where my controllers return a view model so the client application can show the data into grids.

This is a sample Controller with a sample Method so I can explain better:

```
public class SampleController: ApiControllerBase
{ 
     [HttpGet, AppAuthorize(null)]
     public HttpResponseMessage GetSampleData(int employeeId, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
     {
         HttpResponseMessage returnVal = null;

         // THIS IS NEW, SO INSTEAD OF RETURNING A MODEL I WILL RETURN A FILE
         // BUT I DON'T WANT TO ADD THIS TO EVERY CONTROLLER, I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE IT IN A BASE CONTROLLER OR SOMETHING?
         // CHECK IF USER REQUEST TO EXPORT GRID TO EXCEL

         if (this.Request.GetQueryStrings().ContainsKey("exportdata"))
         {
             // here I will have to generate the excel file

             returnVal = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

             returnVal.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);

             returnVal.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
             returnVal.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
             returnVal.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

             return returnVal;
         }

         var model = SampleRepository.GetConsumptionSummary(employeeId, fromDate.ToUniversalTime().Date, toDate.ToUniversalTime().Date);

         if (model != null)
         {
             returnVal = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Model.Custom.JsonResponse {
                 data = model,
                 message = "",
                 num = model.Count,
                 success = true
             });
         } else {
             returnVal = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Model.Custom.JsonResponse {
                 data = null,
                 message = "There was an error processing the data.",
                 num = 0,
                 success = false,
                 code = "ERR-001"
             });
         }

         return returnVal;
     }
 }
```

On the client, the user can request to export the same grid data to excel. In this scenario I will use the same method for the grid to generate an excel file and return to the browser.

```
if (this.Request.GetQueryStrings().ContainsKey("exportdata"))
{
}
```

This line does the magic in the method so I know if the user has requested to export the data to excel.

But, I don't want to put that logic on each method on each controller, I would like to have in a separate place but that applies to all methods.

> I was thinking in creating a `Filter` that I can just place in the methods or controllers where I want to happen that logic.

The code that I should be using in my Filter or an alternative approach would be:

```
// CHECK IF USER REQUEST TO EXPORT GRID TO EXCEL
if (this.Request.GetQueryStrings().ContainsKey("exportdata"))
{
    // here I will have to generate the excel file...

    returnVal = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    returnVal.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
    returnVal.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    returnVal.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
    returnVal.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return returnVal;
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: What about returning `return myFunc(Request, model)` where `myFunc` is a function that decides what kind of response needs to be sent back to the user?

Comment: How does your excel generation work? Is it generic or on some kind of base class / interface? If so a `MediaTypeFormatter` could work.

Answer (score 1):

You have the [FileStreamResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult(v=vs.118).aspx) that should help you, so you don't have to always declare too much things.

I would create a custom [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx). In one of our applications we use a custom "ExcelResult" like this :

```
public class ExcelResult : FileStreamResult
{
    public ExcelResult(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
        : base(fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    {
        FileDownloadName = fileName;
    }
}
```

So when we need to generate and return an Excel file, we do something like this (we even extracted this bit as a method in our "BaseController") :

```
using (MemoryStream result = (MemoryStream)ExportService.ExportToExcel(foo))
{
    return Excel(new MemoryStream(result.GetBuffer()), fileName);
}
```

And the Excel method (in our base controller) :

```
public ExcelResult Excel(Stream stream, string fileName)
{
    if (stream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

    return new ExcelResult(stream, fileName);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is how to organize this for many models, not the actual implementation of the response.